# How can this statement be written in JOOQ?

Tags: jooq, mysql-5.6

I have a table that has `ID varchar(255)` as PK. I have managed to create an auto increment temporary column `rowNumber` to use with a SELECT, as follows:

```
SELECT
   (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, ID  
  from table
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS n 
where 
  (
    some conditions
    )
  )
  and date > {ts '2020-08-06 08:51:23.08'}
  ORDER BY ID
  LIMIT 10
;
```

How can the above query be expressed in `JOOQ`? Especially, the `(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SQL variable support in jOOQ

jOOQ currently (version 3.13) doesn't support session variables like the ones you've shown. There's a pending feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2558

Whenever jOOQ doesn't support a vendor specific feature, you can use it via [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), instead. Write:

```java
ctx
  .select(
    field("(@cnt := @cnt + 1)", SQLDataType.BIGINT).as("rowNumber"),
    TABLE.ID)
  .from(TABLE)
  .crossJoin(table(select(field("@cnt := 0", SQLDataType.BIGINT))).as("n"))
  .where(...)
  .orderBy(TABLE.ID)
  .limit(10)
  .fetch();
```

Assuming, as always, this static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### Starting from MySQL 8

Just a side-note for future visitors who might be using MySQL 8: In those cases, you'd be using the [`DSL.rowNumber()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#rowNumber()) window function instead of the approach using variables